# Error with stripe webhooks to controller rails backend

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, heroku-postgres, stripe-payments

I am sending webhooks from stripe to my controller action successfully in a local environment, but when I try this in production, all webhooks are failing with  `403 (Forbidden)`  could it have something to do with Cloudflare for example?

Comment: That error means that your webhook endpoint is likely set up to require some sort of authentication, which Stripe doesn't have so the events are being returned with an error. You should look at your server settings and make sure the endpoint is accessible to the wider internet.

Comment: How could I assess that? I am using Heroku